# unable to setup to use vee-validate with laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2

I am new to vue and trying to integrate it in one of my project in which I am using Laravel 5.4. I am using vee-validate for validation purpose. I am using yarn to manage packages. When I am accessing the page after npm run dev I am getting following errors in the firebug console bar:

```
TypeError: value is undefined               (this one is in app.js file)
ReferenceError: require is not defined  (this one is in plugin.js file)
```

This is my app.js file:

```
/**                                                                             
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which       
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when          
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.            
 */

require('./bootstrap');                                                         
import VeeValidate from 'vee-validate'                                          

Vue.use(VeeValidate);

/**                                                                             
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to       
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application          
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.            
 */
Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));                  
Vue.component('form-account-create', require('./components   /CreateAccount.vue'));

const app = new Vue({                                                           
    el: '#app'                                                                  
});
```

This is my webpack.mix.js file:

```
    mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')                               
       .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');                       

    //copying the font-awesome fonts                                                
    mix.copy('./node_modules/font-awesome/fonts', 'public/bulids/fonts');           

    /**                                                                             
     * concatenating multiple plugins css into one file                             
     */                                                                             
    mix.styles([                                                                    
        './node_modules/metismenu/dist/metisMenu.min.css',                      
        './node_modules/gritter/css/jquery.gritter.css',                        
        './resources/assets/css/animate.css',                                   
        './resources/assets/css/style.css',                                     
        './resources/assets/css/custom.css'                                     
], 'public/css/plugins.css');                                                   


/**                                                                             
 * concatenating multiple plugins js into one file                              
 */                                                                             
mix.scripts([                                                                   
        './node_modules/metismenu/dist/metisMenu.js',                           
        './node_modules/slimscroll/lib/slimscroll.js',                          
        './node_modules/gritter/js/jquery.gritter.js',                          
        './resources/assets/js/inspinia/inspinia.js',                           
        './node_modules/pace/pace.js',                                          
        './resources/assets/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js'                 
    /*        './resources/assets/js/inspinia/custom.js' */                         
    ], 'public/js/plugins.js');
```

I am currently stuck at this point and don't know how to fix these issue. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time to read through this question.

Answer (score 0):

This repository works: **https://github.com/kanokpit-skuberg/loverflow**

1. In **resources/assets/js/app.js** file
   You should put `import VeeValidate from 'vee-validate';`
   under `window.Vue = require('vue');`
2. In **webpack.mix.js** file
   The *pace.js* or *pace.min.js* file, should be manual download ([pace](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome)).
   Because the pace.js from `npm install pace` contain code `require('charm')` that client-side not allowed.